# como tratar diferentes index/templates para um mesmo site?

Tags: php, htaccess, template

Tenho 10 templates html/php distintos e via painel (admin) o cliente pode selecionar um dos 10 templates para o seu site.

Minha dúvida é como fazer para o site saber qual template deve abrir. No painel eu guardo o template selecionado na base.

No site como faço para que, por exemplo, abra o index do template09 ou o index do template02 sendo que está tudo em pastas separadas?

ex. templeate01/index, template02/index....

Sem que para apareça na url o redirecionamento (fulano.com.br/template09).

Consigo tratar o htaccess com php? Alguma dica ou exemplo?

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, na hora de fazer o include, você consulta o banco, lê o recurso e usa o valor armazenado como parte do *path* de inclusão.

Comment: é isso mesmo, simples assim...

Answer (score 2):

Pra esse problema tem dezenas/centenas talvez até milhares de soluções possíveis. Vou postar uma estrutura que eu utilizava.

#### Estrutura

```
\
|__ Templates\
|   |__ Default\
|   |   |__ css\
|   |   |__ js\
|   |   |__ img\
|   |   |__ index.php
|   |
|   |__ Dark\
|   |   |__ css\
|   |   |__ js\
|   |   |__ img\
|   |   |__ index.php
|   |
|   |__ Light\
|       |__ css\
|       |__ js\
|       |__ img\
|       |__ index.php
|
|__ Pages\
|   |__ home.php
|   |__ contato.php
|   |__ sobre.php
|   |__ 404.php
|
|__ index.php /* Código do arquivo abaixo */
|__ menu.php
```

#### index.php

```
define('TITULO', 'Site com vários templates');
$page = (!empty($_GET['page']) $_GET['page'] : 'home';

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'\\pages\\'.$page.'php'))
   define('PAGE' file_exists(__DIR__.'\\pages\\'.$page.'php'));
else
   define('PAGE', __DIR__.'\\pages\\404.php');

define('MENU', __DIR__.'\\menu.php');

// Este valor pode ser recebido do  banco de dados, ou de algum arquivo de configuração
$template = "Default";

require_once __DIR__.'\\Templates\\'.$template.'\\index.php';
```

#### Arquivos dos templates

Em cada arquivo `index.php` de cada template você deve ter seu código HTML e arquivos como CSS e Javascript deve ser referênciado com caminho absoluto, por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=TITULO?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meudominio.com/Templates/Default/estilos.css">
<script src="http://meudominio.com/Templates/Default/arquivo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require_once MENU;            
        require_once PAGE;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O que eu faço é uma pesquisa no banco e pego qual o tema que o usuário esta usando e faço isso:

```
switch ($retornoBanco) {
    case 0:
        include="tema1.php";
        break;
    case 1:
        include="tema2.php";
        break;
    case 2:
        include="tema3.php";
        break;
    default:
        include="temaDefault.php";
        break;
```

Ai você faz isso dinamicamente e adiciona a página dentro do index principal.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para que a resposta tenha a visibilidade merecida, vou repostar a solução ora dada em comentário.

Se entendi corretamente, na hora de fazer o include/require, você consulta o valor armazenado no banco de dados, lê o recurso obtido e usa o valor armazenado como parte do *path* de inclusão.

Simple e direito ^_^

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o OP não sabe como fazer isso...

Comment: Eu me abstive de colocar um pseudo-código por causa da resposta dele logo acima. Se for necessário, eu complemento.